# JasmineReporters JUnitXmlReporter not writing file

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I have protractor tests running with webdriver.  The tests run, but the jasmine-reporter is not writing the output file.

protractor_conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
    // Do not start a Selenium Standalone sever - only run this using chrome.
    //chromeOnly: true,
    //chromeDriver: '../node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver',

    //we are using a standalone selenium server so give it the local address
    seleniumAddress: 'http://0.0.0.0:4444/wd/hub',
    //seleniumPort: 4444,
    //seleniumServerJar: './selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar',


    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000',

    onPrepare: function () {
        var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
        var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
        capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
            var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.toUpperCase();
            var browserVersion = caps.caps_.version;
            var prePendStr = browserName + '-' + browserVersion + '-';
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter('test/test-results/protractor', true, true, prePendStr));
        });
    },

    specs: ['test/protractor/**/*-spec.js'],

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        isVerbose: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },

    params: {
        env: 'development',
        homepageUrl: 'http://localhost:9000'
    }
};
```

Test output:

```
/usr/local/bin/node --debug-brk=60603 --nolazy node_modules/protractor/lib/cli.js protractor_conf-dev.js
debugger listening on port 60603
Using the selenium server at http://0.0.0.0:4444/wd/hub
E2E: verify main page loads and correct items are there
  when the main page loads, the content should be available - pass


Finished in 0.727 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 0 failures


Process finished with exit code 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks a lot like you are trying to combine `jasmine-reporters@2.0.0` with Protractor. Protractor currently supports Jasmine 1.x, not Jasmine 2.x. I suspect you want to use `~1.0.0` of jasmine-reporters. It also looks like you are trying to combine jasmine-reporters 1.x syntax with 2.x reporters.

- It looks like you are using 2.0.0 because of `var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');` and `new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter( /* ... */ );`

  - jasmine-reporters 1.x doesn't have an `index.js` and doesn't export anything, so you should get `TypeError: undefined is not a function` if trying the above code with 1.x reporters
- It looks like you are combining 1.x syntax with 2.x reporters because the 2.x JUnitXmlReporter expects a config object rather than ordered parameters.

Your code should look a lot more like this if you are using jasmine-reporters 1.x:

```
require('jasmine-reporters');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
    new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('test/test-results/protractor', true, true, prePendStr)
);
```

Comment: Yeah, I had "jasmine-reporters": "^2.0.0" in my package.json.  Changed it to a lower version, and put the code back to what you cited (which was failing earlier at new jasmine.JUnitXmlReport due to version)

Comment: For jasmine 2.x, the modification that needs to be done is-
`var jasmineReporter = require('jasmine-reporters');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
    new jasmineReporter .JUnitXmlReporter('test/test-results/protractor', true, true, prePendStr)
);`

Comment: @RahulVig That's close, but jasmine-reporters 2.x doesn't use ordered parameters anymore. So your last bit would need to be `new jasmineReporter.JUnitXmlReporter({savePath: 'test/test-results/protractor', filePrefix: prePendStr});` -- both useDotNotation and consolidate are true by default.